# Posix server-client application gets stucked during communication

Tags: c, unix, client-server, posix

I'm learning C in posix standard. I'm trying to create client-server application, and right now I try to handle communication between them.

I didn't know how to properly let client know when he is supposed to send something to server. What I came up with is simple - when server sends message "1" it means it now waits for client's input.

I first tried with telnet and it somehow worked. Problems came when I created client application - it worked ONCE. And later it decided to stop working. Server properly gets one input from client (when he chooses "AddObject" option) and later it stops working (client doesn't know server waits for a message).

I've tried to clean up my code as much as possible (my actual code is a huge, since I often try different things and have a lot of comments), but it sill probably sucks - sorry for that.

server

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define maxnamel 50
#define BUFLEN 512
#define ERR(source) (fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__),\
                     perror(source),kill(0,SIGKILL),\
                         exit(EXIT_FAILURE))

struct arg_struct {
    int fd;
    int org;
};

void usage(void);
int make_socket(uint16_t port);                  


void usage(void){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./all\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


void sendAndPrint(char* wiadomosc, int sock){

    write((int)sock , wiadomosc , strlen(wiadomosc));
    printf("%s",wiadomosc);
}


int make_socket(uint16_t port) {
    struct sockaddr_in name;
    int sock, t=1;

    sock = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if (sock < 0) ERR("socket");

    name.sin_family = AF_INET;
    name.sin_port = htons(port);
    name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &t, sizeof(t))) ERR("setsockopt");
    if (bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*) &name, sizeof(name)) < 0) ERR("bind");
    return sock;
}

void addObject (int sock)
{
    int read_size, read_size_sum;
    char* buf;
    char *record;
    record=malloc(sizeof(char)*100+1);

    buf=malloc(sizeof(char)*10+1);
    sendAndPrint("AddObject.\n", sock);
    sendAndPrint("Add details of new object.\n", sock);
    sendAndPrint("Name:\n", sock);
    sleep(0.5);
    sendAndPrint("1", sock);
    read_size = recv(sock, buf, maxnamel, 0);
    printf("%s", buf);
    read_size-=1;
    buf[read_size]=0;
    read_size_sum = read_size;
    strcpy(record,buf); 

    record[read_size-1]=0;

    sendAndPrint("Age:\n", sock);
    sendAndPrint("1\n", sock);
    read_size = recv(sock, buf, 10, 0);
    read_size-=1;
    buf[read_size+1]=0;
    read_size_sum +=read_size;
    strcat(record,"-");
    strcat(record,buf);

    record[read_size_sum-2]=0;

    sendAndPrint("Weight:\n", sock);
    sendAndPrint("1", sock);
    read_size = recv(sock, buf, 10, 0);
    buf[read_size-1]=0;
    read_size_sum +=read_size;
    strcat(record,"-");
    strcat(record,buf);
    record[read_size_sum-3]=0;

    sendAndPrint("Number:\n", sock);
    sendAndPrint("1", sock);
    read_size = recv(sock, buf, 10, 0);
    buf[read_size-1]=0;
    read_size_sum +=read_size;
    strcat(record,"-");
    strcat(record,buf);
    record[read_size_sum-3]=0;

    strcat(record,"-0");
    strcat(record,"\n");

}

void *connection_handler(void *sock_desc)
{
    return 0;
}

void *organizer_handler(void *sock_desc)
{
    int wybor, read_size;
    char client_message[1000];
    int sock = *(int*)sock_desc;


    sendAndPrint("Start.\n",sock);
    sendAndPrint("Choose your action:\n\n1 - Add Object\n2 - To Do\n3 - To Do\n",sock);
    sendAndPrint("4 - To Do\n\n\n", sock);
    sendAndPrint("1", sock);
    while((read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 100 , 0)) > 0 )
    {


        wybor=atoi(client_message);

        if((wybor==1))
            addObject(sock);
        else
            {
                sendAndPrint("Wrong choice.\n\n",sock);
                sleep(3);
            }


        sendAndPrint("Choose your action:\n\n1 - Add Object\n2 - To Do\n3 - To Do\n",sock);
        sendAndPrint("4 - To Do\n\n\n", sock);
    }
    return 0;
}


void *doClient(void *arguments){

    struct arg_struct *args = arguments;

    int fd = args -> fd;
    int org = args -> org;

    int backlog=10; 
    int l, c,client_sock, *new_sock;
    fd_set set;
    pthread_t sniffer_thread2;

    struct sockaddr_in client;
    l=listen(fd, backlog);
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    puts("Thread created.");


    while(1)
    {

    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET (fd, &set);
    puts("Waiting for connection...");

    while((client_sock = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)))
        {           


            new_sock = malloc(1);
            *new_sock = client_sock;

            if (org == 1)
            { 

                puts("Organizer has connected. Creating thread...");
                if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread2 , NULL ,  organizer_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
                {
                    perror("Could not create thread for organizer.");
                    return 0;
                }
            } else
            {
                puts("Normal client has connected. Creating thread...");
                if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread2 , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
                {
                    perror("Could not create thread for normal client.");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

void doServer(int fd){

    pthread_t sniffer_thread;
    char message[1000];
    struct arg_struct orgArgs;

    orgArgs.fd = fd;
    orgArgs.org = 1;

    puts("Started server.");
    puts("Creating a thread for organizer client...");

    if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  doClient , (void *)&orgArgs) < 0)
            {
                perror("Could not create thread for doClient for organizers.");
                return;
            }

        puts("Type 1 if you want to stop server.");
        while (scanf("%s", message))
        {
            if(atoi(message) == 1)
        {
            puts("Closing server.");
            break;
        }
        else
            puts("Type 1 if you want to stop server.");
        }   
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int fd;
    uint16_t port=8089;

    if(argc != 1){
        usage();
    }

    fd = make_socket(port);

    doServer(fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

client

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define HERR(source) (fprintf(stderr,"%s(%d) at %s:%d\n",source,h_errno,__FILE__,__LINE__),\
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE))
#define BUFLEN 512
#define ERR(source) (fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__),\
                     perror(source),kill(0,SIGKILL),\
                         exit(EXIT_FAILURE))

int fd;

int make_socket(void){
    int sock;
    sock = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sock < 0) ERR("socket");
    return sock;
}

struct sockaddr_in make_address(uint16_t port){
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    struct hostent *hostinfo;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons (port);
    hostinfo = gethostbyname("localhost");
    if(hostinfo == NULL)HERR("gethostbyname");
    addr.sin_addr = *(struct in_addr*) hostinfo->h_addr;
    return addr;
}

int connect_socket(uint16_t port){
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int socketfd;
    socketfd = make_socket();
    addr=make_address(port);
    if(connect(socketfd,(struct sockaddr*) &addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0){
        if(errno!=EINTR) ERR("connect");
        else { 
            fd_set wfds;
            int status;
            socklen_t size = sizeof(int);
            FD_ZERO(&wfds);
            FD_SET(socketfd, &wfds);
            if(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(select(socketfd+1,NULL,&wfds,NULL,NULL))<0) ERR("select");
            if(getsockopt(socketfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_ERROR,&status,&size)<0) ERR("getsockopt");
            if(0!=status) ERR("connect");
        }
    }
    return socketfd;
}

void doClientORG(int fd){
    int read_size;
    int msg_size;
    char client_message[1000];
    char message[1000];

    puts("Waiting for server.");
    while((read_size = recv(fd , client_message , 100 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        client_message[read_size]=0;
        if(atoi(client_message) == 1)
        {
            puts("Inside");
            scanf("%s", message);

            /*printf("Message: %s\n\n", message);*/
            write(fd, message,1);

        }
        else
            printf("%s", client_message);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int fd;
    uint16_t port=8089;
    char* message;
    fd=connect_socket(port);


    doClientORG(fd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any ideas? Did I do something wrong, or is my idea incorrect to begin with?

Comment: If you are programming against POSIX, why do you define `_GNU_SOURCE`?

Comment: You are trying to re-invent a bicycle. Google for "sockets usage examples" and similar things.. You'll get some good ideas from there.

Comment: As I said my code is a mess - _GNU_SOURCE is only #defined and isn't used anywhere. Regarding socket examples - I'll look for that, but can you expand on the topic? You mean the way I connect to sockets or the way I try to communicate through them? Should I use other functions?

Comment: Definining `_GNU_SOURCE` ***is*** using it.  It causes the compiler (if it's `gcc`, at least) to accept GNU extensions to the C language, and it causes the standard library headers of glibc to declare extra functions and macros.  If you are truly programming against POSIX then you should instead define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` with a value indicative of the version of POSIX on which you are relying.  You may also need to use appropriate compiler options to disable extensions -- for example, `-std=c99`.

Comment: Thanks for this information - I did not know that. Still the main problem remains - I have no idea why communication starts failing after first client message.
After looking for some examples I've tried using bzero() function but without results.

Comment: Your server's `doClient()` function looks highly suspicious.  I'm not sure what you expect to be the result of passing the descriptor for a connected socket to `listen()`, but one way or another it cannot be good.  In any event, it's a recipe for disaster to have two threads concurrently manipulating the same file descriptor.

Comment: None of changes seem to be helping. Maybe let's go from the other side - my way of prompting client to write (sending him '1' message) is clearly not working. What would be a correct way of informing client that I need him to send me something right now?

Comment: The method of informing the client is acceptable.   However, when generating the sockets, be sure to enable the 'keepalive' option otherwise any delay in the communication will result in the socket being closed

Comment: why this: `kill(0,SIGKILL),` in the `ERR` macro?   it will result in the current process being killed, so will never get to the next expression: `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings. then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )   Both of the posted programs do not cleanly compile so they both need to be corrected.

Comment: regarding this line: `client_message[read_size]=0;`  The expectation is the code is trying NUL terminate the message read in.   Due to implicit conversions, this may work.  However, you should always write code that is clear.   Note: a integer 0 is 0x00000000 (and 8 more 0s if on a 64 bit architecture)  what is wanted is a NUL byte.  I.E. `\0'   Suggest: `client_message[read_size]= '\0';`

Comment: When calling function: `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling your `usage()` function, Strongly suggest passing `argv[0]` as an argument, modify the `usage()` function to expect a `char *` parameter.  Then the call to fprintf() would be: `fprint( stderr, "Usage: %\n". parmName);`  where 'parmName' is replaced with the actual parameter name from the usage() function signature

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers (for instance 10 and 100). 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: it is wise (but usually not mandatory) to check the returned value from a call to `write()` to assure the whole data block was sent.

Comment: the function: `sleep()` only takes an integer parameter, not a double parameter.  So this line: `sleep(0.5);` needs to be corrected

Comment: when preparing to call the `recv()` function, it might be wise to first call the `select()` function, with a modest timeout value, say 1/2 second

Comment: The function: `recv()` does not NUL terminate the data read.  So these line: `read_size = recv(sock, buf, maxnamel, 0);
    printf("%s", buf);
    buf[read_size]=0;`  will fail for two reasons: 1) if any byte in the data read contains '\0' the call to `printf()` will stop before displaying the whole data.  2) if no byte in the data read contains a '\0' then undefined behaviour will occur as the call to `printf()` will try to print past the end of the actual data (even past the end of the `buf` input buffer).  Suggest terminating the buffer before trying to print it.

Comment: a call to `recv()`, over a socket, will not necessarily read all the data sent by the sender.   Strongly suggest adding a byte count to the start of the sent data or employing a know/unique terminator/delimiter so the code knows when it has actually received all the data.

Comment: what are you expecting this line: `record[read_size-1]=0;` to perform?  What it actually does is throw away the last character of the data received,, Then this line: `record[read_size_sum-3]=0;` throws away three more bytes of the input

Comment: regarding multiplying anything by `sizeof(char)` is a total waste of time.  the expression, is defined in the C standard as always being 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.

Comment: in the function: `addobject()`, the variable `record` is created from a call to `malloc()`  1) that pointer is never passed to `free()`, so the code has a memory leak (similiar with `buf`)  2) the variable `record` is not visible outside the `addobject()` function, so any manipulation of that variable is a waste of time and code.  As it is only used to accumulate the data received via the socket, but nothing is ever done with that variable

Comment: strongly suggest reading (carefully) the man pages for `strcpy()` and `strcat()`

Comment: to correct a warning issued by the compiler about the function: `connection_handler()` regarding an unused parameter,  suggest inserting the line: `(void)sock_desc;` as the first line in the body of the function

Comment: when calling `listen()`,  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding these two line: `new_sock = malloc(1);
            *new_sock = client_sock;`,  an integer (the socket value) is 4 bytes (8 bytes on a 64 bit architecture) NOT 1 byte.  so the call to `malloc()` should be: `new_sock = malloc( sizeof(int) );`

Comment: in function: `doClient()`, there are `return 0` statements but there is not call to `free()` for the allocated memory gotten via `malloc()`  this results in a memory leak.  Strongly suggest you use `valgrind` or similar tool to help you find/fix the many memory leaks in the posted code.

Comment: when a thread has been started via a call to `pthread_create()`, then the code needs to call `pthread_join()` *somewhere* to wait for that thread to complete/exit.   Note: much better to have a 'pool' of threads generated once then use them as needed rather than spending the time, CPU cycles, etc to generate each thread as needed and destroying each thread after using it once.  generating/destroying each thread, as needed, will make your code very 'unresponsive' to client requests.

Comment: there are a lot more problems with the code besides the above comments.  However, the above comments should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Wow, thank You a lot for all your input and the time you have invested into this. I'll take into consideration all your advices and try to fix my program.